# Simple Stability and Feedback

Tags: feedback, stability, phase, system, negative-feedback

I have a question, my book says that for the system in this picture:

[image: block diagram of a closed loop system G(s) with feedback -H(s) with some impulse input]

If the system has G(s)*H(s) with a module of 1 (0dB) and a phase of -180°, the system is in Simple Stability, so it is like in this picture:

[image: drawing of a ball that moves from point A to B, showing it is simply stable]

So if we apply a disturbance, the disturbance will not make the output grown too much, since the new point of stability will be translated not far from the old point of stability, but now I have 2 questions:

1. How is it possible that the output will not go to infinite? I mean we have \$ \frac{G(s)}{1-1} = \frac{G(s)}{0}=\infty \$, so the system will be blown up, but my book said that the system will be stabilized to a point near the old point of stability.[Note that we have -1, because module 1 and -180° mean a signal of -1 (The - is added by the 180° phase)].
2. Let's assume that we have a stable system, \$W(s)\$, so with a module of for example -100(-40dB) and a phase of -180°, if a disturbance is applied,for example 1V (I know that in reality this will be impossible) the disturbance will become a disturbance of -1V, and when it go in the feedback node since in the node there is a -, we will obtain a positive feedback that will destroy the system, how is it possible that this system is stable?

Comment: I think you are misquoting your book.

Comment: ...or the book is wrong. The required phase shift of -180deg is contained in the shoewn minus sign at the summing junction. Hence, it is the loop gain LG=-GH which must exhibit the -180deg. Then, the product GH is positive (0 deg. phase shift).